# MONGODB find product number

Tags: c#, mongodb, compass

I have a MONGODB with some test results (>25.000), the DB contain around ~50 product numbers.

Is there away for me to get a list with productnumbers? (~50 insted of >25.000)

I use C# and compass

I guess it's pretty simple :-)
Best regards.
SPA..

Comment: It seems that you want to group by product number. You'll find a lot of examples when you google for c# mongodb groupby. If you have concrete problems, post what you have and what's not working - we're here to help.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to interact with MongoDB you have to add these lines in the top of your code, above everuthing:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;  
using MongoDB.Driver;  
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;  
using MongoDB.Driver.GridFS;  
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

---

Now we are going to create the connection to the DB:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(your_connection_string);  
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();  
MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase(your_db_name);
```

Now it's time to create a collection of your data:

```
MongoCollection resultsCollection = null; 
try   
     {   
        resultsCollection = database.GetCollection<results>(your_results_name);   
        Console.WriteLine(resultsCollection.Count().ToString());   
     }   
     catch (Exception ex)   
     {   
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to Get collection from Database");   
        Console.WriteLine("Error :" + ex.Message);   
     }
```

With the collection of data coded above, we create a list based on query results:

```
List< Results > query = resultsCollection.AsQueryable<Entity>().Where<Entity>(your_where_statement).Limit(50).ToList();
```

For this example I created a class `Results` in order to give an idea:

```
public class Results  
{   
   public string Name { get; set; }   
   public ObjectId ID { get; set; }   
}
```

---

***Remarks:***

If you want to get from the query only an *x* numbers of results, you have to use `.Limit(number_of_rows)`